# How to force user to type username & password for LXDM Login Window Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, login, lxdm

Is it possible to remove the drop down box with the list of users on the login window to Lubuntu and replace it with a text field that forces the user to type in both the Username and Password. Currently you are able to select a username from the drop down menu and I would like to disable this feature. I have been unable to find any answers to this in the forums so far.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Type following to edit `lxdm.conf`:

`sudo gedit /etc/lxdm/lxdm.conf`

For  Lubuntu it is :

`sudo gedit /etc/xdg/lubuntu/lxdm/lxdm.conf`.

Now search for following line

`[userlist]
 ##if disable the user list control at greeter
 disable=0`

Change the `disable=0` to  `disable=1`

Now you will get textbox instead of userlist to enter username at login screen.

Comment: In /etc/lxdm there is only default.conf. I edited that as you suggested and rebooted but it still kept the usernames in the list. I also tried editing /etc/xdg/lubuntu/lxdm/lxdm.conf with the same setting but with no luck. Any other advice?

Comment: Have you rebooted your system?

Comment: Yes on both attempts

Comment: I have installed lxdm in my system and above configuration is working fine. Let me google about your problem.

Comment: try `sudo update-alternatives --config lxdm.conf`,select prefered config and try again.

Comment: Output from command -- There is only one alternative in link group lxdm.conf (providing /etc/lxdm/default.conf): /etc/xdg/lubuntu/lxdm/lxdm.conf
Nothing to configure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13424/discussion-between-guru-and-user255433)

Comment: Oh my, I've made a fool of myself! Of course it is LightDM and not LXDM! Edited the /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf with the following - greeter-show-manual-login=true
greeter-hide-users=true
allow-guest=false